# Distinct (dplyr) not working well - unique observation based on criteria

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, dplyr

I have some data with duplicated records and some of them should not be there (`mark` and `recov` should be only once per `band`, `recap` can be present several times). I want to select unique observations (`band`) based on certain values in a column (`variable=="mark"`) and keep the rest of the data from `"recap"` and `"recov"`.

I used `dyplr`, to group my data by band then select unique record when column `variable=="mark"`, this is my code:

```
uniq <- df %>%group_by(band)  %>% distinct(variable=="mark")
```

I found out that it is not working well, when looking for certain observations another values from `variable=="recap"` have been deleted (example: in `band=113749924`, the recap value from 1993 is missing, same case in `band=113728509` there is a recap value missing)

This is a data example:

```
structure(list(band = c(113728501L, 113728502L, 113728503L, 113728504L, 
113728505L, 113728505L, 113728506L, 113728506L, 113728507L, 113728508L, 
113728509L, 113728509L, 113728509L, 113728509L, 113728510L, 113728510L, 
113729709L, 113729709L, 113729709L, 113729710L, 113729711L, 113729712L, 
113729713L, 113729714L, 113729715L, 113729716L, 113729717L, 113729718L, 
113729719L, 113729720L, 113729720L, 113729721L, 113729722L, 113729723L, 
113729724L, 113729725L, 113729726L, 113729727L, 113729728L, 113729729L, 
113729730L, 113729731L, 113729732L, 113729733L, 113729733L, 113729733L, 
113729734L, 113729735L, 113729735L, 113729735L, 113729914L, 113729914L, 
113729914L, 113729914L, 113729915L, 113729916L, 113729917L, 113729918L, 
113729919L, 113729920L, 113729921L, 113729922L, 113729923L, 113729924L, 
113729925L, 113729926L, 113729927L, 113729928L, 113729929L, 113749923L, 
113749924L, 113749924L, 113749924L), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("mark", "recap", 
"recov"), class = "factor"), year = c(1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 
1994L, 2012L, 1994L, 1999L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 2002L, 
2003L, 1994L, 1996L, 1994L, 2002L, 1998L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 
1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1995L, 
1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 
1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 2002L, 2001L, 1994L, 1994L, 1999L, 
1998L, 1994L, 1994L, 1999L, 2005L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 
1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 
1994L, 1994L, 1991L, 1991L, 1994L, 1993L)), .Names = c("band", 
"variable", "year"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-73L))
```

At the end I would like to have something like (example for 113749924):

```
band      year variable
113749924 1991 mark
113749924 1993 recap
113749924 1994 recov
```

Could you please help me to find what is wrong or maybe suggest me an alternative code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Posting data inline as output of `dput` is the best way to get help. External links are not useful.

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice! I've learnt something new today

Comment: You can try `distinct(df)`. Or, if you use `group_by`, you can use `slice` to get just the first row of duplicated set.

Comment: Is that the three rows you want as expected output?  Based on the data showed, you don't have any duplicates for `mark` in the `band` 113749924 .

Comment: Um, `DF %>% group_by(variable) %>% slice(n())` ? Your desired output is just the last row for each distinct value of variable...

Comment: It is just an example, I want all the combinations that are present for the different values of "variable".

Comment: @MSS Have you tried my updated solution?

Comment: Hi @akrun, thank you for the update, this code works for the band 113749924, but the band 113728509 still has double "mark" value.

Comment: @MSS In my output, I can only find one `mark` for 113728509

Comment: You are right @akrun, it works with the data example (which has 2 marks and 2 recaps), but in the complete dataset it is still the same. What else can  it be? it is exactly the same format of the data, the difference is that the complete dataset is almost 80,000 records.

Comment: @MSS I also added a second solution.   Please check if that works.  Regarding the problem, in the big dataset, it could be that you have leading/lagging spaces  in the 'variable'.  In that case, try with `df %>% mutate(variable = trimws(variable)) %>% group_by(band)...`

Comment: The second solution works!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to `group_by` 'band', `filter` the rows where 'variable' is 'mark', get the `distinct` rows and then bind it (`bind_rows`) with a `filter`ed dataset where 'variable' is not 'mark'.

```
df %>% 
 group_by(band) %>% 
 filter(variable=="mark") %>% 
 ungroup() %>%
 distinct() %>%
 bind_rows(., filter(df, variable!="mark")) %>%
 arrange(band) %>%
 data.frame
       band variable year
1  113728501     mark 1994
2  113728502     mark 1994
3  113728503     mark 1994
4  113728504     mark 1994
5  113728505     mark 1994
6  113728505    recov 2012
7  113728506     mark 1994
8  113728506    recap 1999
9  113728507     mark 1994
10 113728508     mark 1994
11 113728509     mark 1994  ###only one mark.
12 113728509    recap 2002
13 113728509    recap 2003
14 113728510     mark 1994
15 113728510    recap 1996
16 113729709     mark 1994
17 113729709    recov 2002
18 113729709    recap 1998
19 113729710     mark 1994
20 113729711     mark 1994
21 113729712     mark 1994
22 113729713     mark 1994
23 113729714     mark 1994
24 113729715     mark 1994
25 113729716     mark 1994
26 113729717     mark 1994
27 113729718     mark 1994
28 113729719     mark 1994
29 113729720     mark 1994
30 113729720    recov 1995
31 113729721     mark 1994
32 113729722     mark 1994
33 113729723     mark 1994
34 113729724     mark 1994
35 113729725     mark 1994
36 113729726     mark 1994
37 113729727     mark 1994
38 113729728     mark 1994
39 113729729     mark 1994
40 113729730     mark 1994
41 113729731     mark 1994
42 113729732     mark 1994
43 113729733     mark 1994
44 113729733    recov 2002
45 113729733    recap 2001
46 113729734     mark 1994
47 113729735     mark 1994
48 113729735    recov 1999
49 113729735    recap 1998
50 113729914     mark 1994
51 113729914    recap 1999
52 113729914    recap 2005
53 113729915     mark 1994
54 113729916     mark 1994
55 113729917     mark 1994
56 113729918     mark 1994
57 113729919     mark 1994
58 113729920     mark 1994
59 113729921     mark 1994
60 113729922     mark 1994
61 113729923     mark 1994
62 113729924     mark 1994
63 113729925     mark 1994
64 113729926     mark 1994
65 113729927     mark 1994
66 113729928     mark 1994
67 113729929     mark 1994
68 113749923     mark 1991
69 113749924     mark 1991
70 113749924    recov 1994
71 113749924    recap 1993
```

---

Or another option would be to `group_by` both 'band', and 'variable', then create a logical condition where the `row_number()` is greater than 1 and 'variable' is 'mark', negate it (`!`) and `filter` the rows.

```
df %>% 
    group_by(band, variable) %>% 
    filter(!(row_number() >1 & variable =="mark"))
```

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I was not clear enough (I already changed it on my post), I also want to keep the rest of the data regarding "recov" and "recap", as well as a unique observation of "mark" (which sometimes is double)

Comment: You can chop out `group_by` and `ungroup`